# When is the driest time to visit Ecuador's El Oriente?

Tags: weather-and-climate, ecuador

In researching when to best visit the rainforests of Ecuador, I've come across conflicting information. [Frommer's](http://www.frommers.com/destinations/ecuador/632174) and [USA Today](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/time-travel-ecuador-13554.html) say the worst (rainiest) time is between December and April. But [Lonely Planet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/ecuador/weather) and [Rough Guide](http://www.roughguides.com/destinations/south-america/ecuador/when-to-go/) roughly agree that the driest time is between December and March.

Can someone help me figure out which one is correct? These sources give exact opposite answers.

Comment: It just seems [there is *a lot* of rain all the time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puyo,_Pastaza). Under this climate, I would assume it rains every day, I am not sure if a few mm more make any difference.

Answer (score 6):

Think about it as *least wet* rather than driest. That would be January to February then but do expect rain at least every other day. Because the ground and roads are mostly dirt, paths can get extremely muddy and due to the shade provided by tropical trees, they remain that way long after it has rained.

Keep in mind that climate varies from year to year and some time it is just an anomaly. I have a great luck in December and even April where each time I enjoyed several consecutive days without rain, once near Misahalli and the other near Yasuni.

There are more variations and more rain at higher-altitude parts of the Oriente such as Puyo. I've never seen not rain for an entire day there.

Comment: (+1) Note that weather varies from year to year. By definition, climate is what's not changing (or at least not so quickly).

Comment: YEah, spot on here. ROads have improved drastically though in the last few years